# tcl: prepend a list of strings using lmap

Tags: tcl

I have the following input: {x y z} and need the output to be {$x $y $z}
It is straightforward to do this using `append` and `foreach`

```
set args {x y z}
#---------------------------------
# using append
#---------------------------------
set result {}
foreach i $args {
    append result " \$[set i]"
}
puts $result ;# $x $y $z
```

But when I tried to use `lmap`, I get the following error 'unknown command '$x'`
I tried the usual quoting tricks but it did not work.

```
#---------------------------------
# using lmap
#---------------------------------
# results in  
# unknown command '$x'
lmap i $args { \$[set i] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a command in the the script body of the lmap command. Perhaps

```
lmap i $args { format {$%s} $i }
```

With Donal's suggestion:

```
lmap i $args { string cat \$ $i }
```

Comment: `string cat` was added _exactly_ for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `set`, but in a slightly different way:

```
lmap i $args {set i "\$$i"}
```

[That is, besides using `string cat` like Donal mentioned in a comment to Glenn's answer]